# show page in iframe with different url in browser

Tags: iframe, treeview, xmldatasource

I apologize because  my English is not good.
I Have a webpage by asp.net  that contain one treeview ,xmldatasource,one xml file that  related to xmldatasource and one iframe.
When  user click on a treenode  a  webpage  will be shown in iframe.
Now I want when treenodes clicked , my url (e.g  "www.mysite.com/default.aspx") change to
("www.mysite.com/default.aspx?onenode")  and if  I directly enter  this url ("www.mysite.com/default.aspx?onenode")   on browser mypage shown and that treenode is selected  and  page(onenode) is shown on iframe  .
there a way to solve the my problem there?
I am waiting for your help.
Thank you for Perpend.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the use of IFRAMEs and use AJAX to render the treenode detail instead. That way you are dealing with just one web page, rather than two, making your problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can easily do this by using the `NavigateUrl` property of the `TreeNode` to set the target URL. (You can construct this based on the `Text/Value` properties of the current TreeNode.

Also, you can set the target frame in which the page is to be loaded by setting the `Target` property of the TreeNode. In your case, it seems you would need to set it to the parent frame (the window itself).